# rake routes rake aborted! ArgumentError: must be called with a path and/or options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

i changed   root :'lesson#index' to
root ('lesson#index')

for the error 
/home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1504:in `root': must be called with a path and/or options (ArgumentError)
    from /home/govisun/Documents/LessonApp/config/routes.rb:5:in`block in '
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in`eval_block'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
    from /home/govisun/Documents/LessonApp/config/routes.rb:1:in`'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in`block in load'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in`load'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`each'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in`reload!'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in`call'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in`updater'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in`block in '
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in`block in tsort_each'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in`each'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in`each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in`tsort_each'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in`initialize!'
    from /home/govisun/Documents/LessonApp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in`load_dependency'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/govisun/Documents/LessonApp/config.ru:3:in`block in '
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`initialize'
    from /home/govisun/Documents/LessonApp/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/govisun/Documents/LessonApp/config.ru:in`'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`new_from_string'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in`build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in`app'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in`log_to_stdout'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in`block in server'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in`server'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
    from /home/govisun/Documents/LessonApp/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/govisun/Documents/LessonApp/bin/rails:8:in`'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in`call'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in`run'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`load'
    from /home/govisun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/govisun/Documents/LessonApp/bin/spring:16:in`require'
    from /home/govisun/Documents/LessonApp/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in`load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `'

and it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `root 'lesson#index'` or `root to:  path`, If you are to use () then make sure there is no space `root('lesson#index')`. Look into the [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource) for more.